# Why wont my AR model load with my image own marker?

Tags: augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

I'm having a issue with loading my own gltf model with an image marker.

https://github.com/ImRCruz/ImRCruz.github.io/blob/main/AR-test-13.html

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I can only use my own model with the preset Hiro marker or the AR.JS example pinball marker/NFT data found in [AR.js/data/dataNFT/](https://github.com/AR-js-org/AR.js)

Not sure what I'm missing. The model doesn't want to load when I try to apply my models descriptor files.

I've tried to use both the NFT Marker Creator in its Web version and the node version but its still nothing.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

lately the ar version of aframe has given problems, even the official github demo doesn't work, in my case now I use this library based on aframe https://hiukim.github.io/mind-ar-js-doc/examples/events -handling/ is even easier to use than aframe and is compatible with all aframe libraries because it is based on it, I recommend it!

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the logs:

```
A-Frame Version: 0.9.2 (Date 2019-12-09, Commit #c4432e7c)
index.js:93 three Version (https://github.com/supermedium/three.js): ^0.111.3
index.js:95 WebVR Polyfill Version: ^0.10.10
WebXR session support error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'hasLoaded')
```

The webxr session won't start because of an outdated library version (a-frame `0.9.2`) - try the [latest one (`1.3.0`)](https://aframe.io/docs/master/introduction/installation.html#include-the-js-build).